# Using Java Robots class to locate things on a screen

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, awtrobot

I was wondering if it was possible to locate files or programs with this class. I know that there are ways to use mouse coordinates or simple find an application and run it but that's not what I want to do.

And example to be more clear is: Let's say I have Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari on my desktop and I shuffle them around all over. How can I get my mouse to find the browser that I'm looking for without simply using a 'run application' command.

I hope that clarifies it! Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (that I know of, using `Robot`) is to record the pixels that make up something you want to find and look for it pixel by pixel (you can compare the current screenshot to an image stored in a file). To do this:

Take a screenshot of the icon you are looking for and save it to a file (just save the icon) (not .jpg, since this is not lossless, probably just .bmp).

Then you can do something like:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage current = robot.createScreenCapture(
  new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

static void getScreenStart()
{
  BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(new File("chromeIcon.bmp"));
  for (int x = 0; x < current.getWidth (); x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < current.getHeight(); y++)
  {
     boolean matches = true;
     for (int x2 = 0; x2 < icon.getWidth () && matches; x2++)
     for (int y2 = 0; y2 < icon.getHeight() && matches; y2++)
        if (icon.getRGB(x2, y2) != current.getRGB(x+x2, y+y2))
           matches = false;
     if (matches)
     {
        X_START = x;
        Y_START = y;
        return;
     }
  }
}
```

But do generally try to avoid doing this when possible.

Comment: That's an interesting fix! What if the screen resolution or coloring is off? Would it still work or would I need to have many of the same image at different resolutions and colors. When I say color I mean 16bit - 32bit - 64bit

Comment: That's why I say "generally try to avoid doing this". You'll need a few of the same images or (no clue how to go about that) do some sort of rounding in the color comparison.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think this is easily achievable using the Robot class. This is because Java is a cross platform language and cannot/does not have the libraries available to integrate into the native environment and window manager.

The Java code needs to run on any platform with a JDK, adding these features to every JDK would be quite a task. I would look into other Java libraries that can provide this functionality, Robots will not provide what you are looking for.

For Windows I would recommend using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which is a scripting language for desktop automation and is very powerful. There is also a port for Mac OSX as [IronAHK](http://www.ironahk.net/).

As for Java libraries depending on what you wish to accomplish you could have a look at some of the GUI automated testing solutions such as [TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools) or even [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). Have a look for test automation tools for Java and you can find even more!

Comment: Okay thanks! Would you know of any libraries that can achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: This will depend on what OS you are using. You may want to use the AutoHotKey language if you are interested in automating Windows, it is very powerful.

Comment: What can I do if I want to locate java ui components on the screen on solaris and aix ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like that for web-crawling, and I can tell you that the tools on the post below will not work that simple. I'm using Selenium for other purposes but it will not work on images where you've got a canvas on the top of all the visible area. To achieve that, you should use the robot class, but previously you have to know the coordinates where you expect it to be. To use some sort of GUI automated testing tool you have to have the fields simply available to be selected. I don't think that you will find it easily on some webpage. Probably to achieve a working solution you'll have to do digital image processing, which is quite good and not that difficult. There are lots of Java libs to do that. Try OpenCV, I think it's JavaCV the lib name, it's a powerful one.